# How to get a count of all objects set with a specific value in field in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to get a count of all objects set that are `False` for the object field `adult`.

I am looping over the "Family" model in my template:

```py
class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Person(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person', related_query_name='person')
    adult = models.BooleanField()
```

Here is what I want to achieve in the template:

```py
# views.py
families = Family.objects.all()
```

```py
# index.html

{% for family in families %}
    {{ family.name }} has {{ family.person(adult=False).count() }} non-adults!
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this counting in your template and not in your view?

Comment: @Chris in my template I loop over "Family" objects that have the model Person as their Foreign Key. So I need to do it for all Family objects

Comment: Please add your Family model and your template. That make it easier to understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I think your problem is best solved by using django annotatations (for details see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)).

In your view annotate each Family object with the numer of adults:

```
families = Family.objects.annotate(non_adults=Count('person', filter=Q(person__adult=False)))
```

Then you can simply use this annotation in your template

```
{% for family in families %}
    {{ family.name }} has {{ family.non_adults }} non-adults!
{% endfor %}
```

With annotations you can utilize the power of the database which is often more effective than querying and doing additional things in python.

Comment: the simplest way